How can I convert H.264 to NTSC for analog video transmission?

For a UAV project we're using an Nvidia Jetson Nano as our mission computer on a fixed wing for object recognition purposes and we agreed that analog video transmission, widely popular with fpv drones, could be the solution to live video feed from the drone to our GCS (due to low cost, simplicity and light weight) but we couldn't figure out how to convert the processed H.264 video output from Jetson to NTSC or PAL to be send to the analog video transmitter.

Is there any way for us to achieve such decoding-encoding process?

I managed to find certain video converters with HDMI input and RCA outputs that I though could be useful but they don't work out either while we won't have a GUI on Jetson to be displayed using HDMI.

Anyone knows a way or equipment for such purposes? Also I'm quite new to the topic thus apologies for any false statements.

I don't think analog video transmission is widely popular with fpv drones. All of DJI's drones transmit FPV using digital video signals now. The best place to get answers to a question about drones would be a drones forum like  https://www.dronevibes.com

@tomh - analogue transmission is widely popular among certain types of drones. Most of my drones are analogue. It is much lower bandwidth, but much lower latency, which is essential for racing drones etc
